# Preselect an element from the list of elements in Material-UI Select component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to preselect the element with the id 3 of my list. If I don't provide a preselected element it should automatically show the disabled item. Currently, the select box only shows *Choose your option* and if I try to pass down *alreadySelected* it's not working and I can't change my option later.

My app component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import CustomSelect from "./components/Select";

function App() {
  const [selectElement, setSelectElement] = React.useState(0);

  // This element should be passed somehow down to the select component
  const alreadySelected = 3;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomSelect
        selectElement={selectElement}
        setSelectElement={setSelectElement}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

My select component:

```
import React from "react";
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select } from "@material-ui/core";

function CustomSelect(props) {
  const { selectElement, setSelectElement } = props;

  const list = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "test 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "test 2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "test 3"
    }
  ];

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSelectElement(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="qualification-type">Select box</InputLabel>
      <Select value={selectElement} onChange={handleChange}>
        <MenuItem disabled value={0}>
          <em>Choose your option</em>
        </MenuItem>
        {list.map(item => (
          <MenuItem key={`type-${item.id}`} value={item.id}>
            {item.name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

CustomSelect.propTypes = {
  selectElement: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  SetSelectElement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default CustomSelect;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState` hook accepts default value as param. You have give 0 as default. Instead:

Use your state default value as 3:
`const [selectElement, setSelectElement] = React.useState(3);`

Yiu can even dynamically derive and pass as default value to state. Let me know.

Comment: How can I set it? The only idea for me is calling `setSelectElement(alreadySelected)` after I defined alreadySelected but i creates too many re-renders

Comment: You didn't notice the three(3) in the code I posted :)

Comment: You are right. I now changed the order and put `const [selectElement, setSelectElement] = React.useState(alreadySelected);` directly under `const alreadySelected = 3;` and it works. I thought the hooks always have to stick at the top of a component as implied by the docs.

Comment: You cannot use it as part of the if condition etc but you can use it in any position before render. Please mark as wer if it worked.